# bridge on interface with public address (ubuntu 20)

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I have a server with one ethernet interface with a public address and i need to configure a bridge for KVM. I know the settings in the local network, where the gateway is on the local address on the router. But i don't know, how to configure a netplan (yaml config), when i have KVM on the machine with direct connection to the public network.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).

Comment: There's no difference. You need to know the upstream gateway. Ask whoever provides your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking this page for various [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges) including your case of a VM on a bridge with external network connectivity.